# How do I Exclude matching rows in two flat files using Informatica?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How do I Exclude matching rows in two flat files using Informatica?

I have a flat file (source) with data that looks like this (normally a lot more data):

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

And a second flat file (source) that look like this:

```
1,2,3
```

I want result (target) to be a flat file that looks like this:

```
4,5,6
```

I know in SQL there is an EXCLUDE (opposite of INTERSECT) that would do the job.  But I am doing this all with flat files and Informatica.

I am pretty new to Informatica.  I have only been doing it for about a month.  So it might be rather obvious.  If you could tell me what Tranformations you would use that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the union transformation to union the result sets from both the files. This would give you the following result set .

```
col1, col2, col3
-----------------
1,2,3
4,5,6
1,2,3
```

After this I would use an aggregator transformation and select these ports (and which ever you want to group by to consider them duplicate) and get the count in the aggregator transformation.

```
After Aggregator (new column count => total_count)
----------------------------------------------------
col1, col2, col3,total_count
-----------------------------
1,2,3,2
4,5,6,1
```

The next step is simple, Pass them through a filter transformation and use the following filter condition to ignore rows which have duplicates.

> total_count = 1

Comment: I would have never thought about it that way.  That is perfect!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Include the first file as a Source, and lookup the second file using a Lookup transformation based on the ports that might match. You can then use a Filter to remove records that had a hit back from the lookup cache.

This method doesn't require any aggregation so it is likely to perform better.